# file_name='export.pkl' 50 ---> 51 predictor = Predict(file_name)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pytorch, streamlit

I'm just trying to recall my model (learner model) of fastai pytorch i've already made, trained and saved in export.pkl  now i'm recalling that model in another deployment app(using streamlit) to to classify the uploaded image based on the previously trained model

---

```
class Predict:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        
        self.learn_inference = load_learner(Path()/filename)
        self.img = self.get_image_from_upload()
        if self.img is not None:
            self.display_output()
            self.get_prediction()
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_image_from_upload():
        uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload Files",type=['png','jpeg', 'jpg'])
        if uploaded_file is not None:
            return PILImage.create((uploaded_file))
        return None

    def display_output(self):
        st.image(self.img.to_thumb(500,500), caption='Uploaded Image')

    def get_prediction(self):

        if st.button('Classify'):
            pred, pred_idx, probs = self.learn_inference.predict(self.img)
            st.write(f'Prediction: {pred}; Probability: {probs[pred_idx]:.04f}')
        else: 
            st.write(f'Click the button to classify') 

if __name__=='__main__':

    file_name='export.pkl'

    predictor = Predict(file_name)
```

and i always get this error, i think it's back to the last 3 lines in the code but i don't understand what's wrong

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2652/833913464.py in <module>
      3     file_name='export.pkl'
      4 
----> 5     predictor = Predict(file_name)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2652/1038630025.py in __init__(self, filename)
     17     def __init__(self, filename):
     18 
---> 19         self.learn_inference = load_learner(Path()/filename)
     20         self.img = self.get_image_from_upload()
     21         if self.img is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_train.py in load_learner(path, file, test, tfm_y, **db_kwargs)
    619     "Load a `Learner` object saved with `export_state` in `path/file` with empty data, optionally add `test` and load on `cpu`. `file` can be file-like (file or buffer)"
    620     source = Path(path)/file if is_pathlike(file) else file
--> 621     state = torch.load(source, map_location='cpu') if defaults.device == torch.device('cpu') else torch.load(source)
    622     model = state.pop('model')
    623     src = LabelLists.load_state(path, state.pop('data'))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    592         pickle_load_args['encoding'] = 'utf-8'
    593 
--> 594     with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
    595         if _is_zipfile(opened_file):
    596             # The zipfile reader is going to advance the current file position.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in _open_file_like(name_or_buffer, mode)
    228 def _open_file_like(name_or_buffer, mode):
    229     if _is_path(name_or_buffer):
--> 230         return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode)
    231     else:
    232         if 'w' in mode:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in __init__(self, name, mode)
    209 class _open_file(_opener):
    210     def __init__(self, name, mode):
--> 211         super(_open_file, self).__init__(open(name, mode))
    212 
    213     def __exit__(self, *args):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'export.pkl\\export.pkl'
```

Comment: You've told us what you're doing but haven't asked a question. What specific part of the problem do you need help with? Why is this question tagged with tkinter? Can you take all of the tkinter parts out and still have the same problem with the `Predict` class?

Comment: Thanks alot, i've updated my question with the error and removed the image link